# How to install autoconf/bison/flex on Github's Windows2019 image?

Tags: c++, windows, github-actions, autotools, package-managers

I am trying to build python wheels for multiple platforms using [cibuildwheel](https://cibuildwheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) on Github Actions, and I have succeeded with the MacOS and Linux images only after installing/upgrading `automake`, `bison`, `flex`, and `swig`. After that, to compile the C++ library and build the wheel it is essentially just `autoreconf/configure/make/make install/python setup.py bdist_wheel`. On the [Windows image](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md), I have tried many different things, but I am just too unfamiliar with Windows to make any progress. `Chocolatey` has `winflexbison3` and `swig`, but does not appear to have `autotools` available. The Windows image README mentions `pacman` as a package manager, but I haven't successfully called it because it's not on PATH.

Is it possible to use a POSIX shell script like `bash` (not `cmd` or `PowerShell`) to do the whole build inside of Github's Windows image? If so, how can I install `automake/autoconf/bison/flex/swig` and then `autoreconf/configure/make/make install`? Specifically, how do I write the script and how do I call it in the Github Actions `yml` file?

Comment: `pacman` on Windows  sounds like it's referring to [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), which for your purposes would presumably be paired with [Mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php).  I see Mingw-w64 listed among the contents of the GitHub Windows environment, but not pacman or many of the other basic tools that MSYS2 would provide, so this probably is not a viable approach for you.

Comment: Bash itself is on the list, but it's unclear whether that also includes the suite of standard tools that Bash scripts commonly rely upon, and that Autoconf `configure` scripts defintely rely upon.  `sed`, for example.  In a general sense, however, you ought to be able to run `bash` commands via the form `bash -c 'some_command -x -y option'`.